# Microsoft SQL Server 2017 developer download error issue

Tags: sql-server

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kza6H.png

I am trying to download SQL Server 2017 developer on my machine and I keep getting an error downloading and an error message pops up as "Cannot find specified path". Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the installer downloads ok but it won't install. You could check the following log (very verbose) to see if that provides any clues.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log

Check out details.txt

Also you could try the install with elevated privileges 'Run as administrator'. I guess you have permissions to the folders?

Comment: Yes I do, I finally fixed it. Thank you!